# Symbol in anonymous namespace when inspecting memory dump in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, memory-dump

### Background

I have a bug report of some server written in C++. Bug report contains description of unexpected behavior and **memory dump**. Now I try fetch information from memory dump. I'm trying inspect memory content of that memory dump.

### Problem

I was able to find pointer to object wish I wish to inspect to analyze issue. It is pointer to some interface. Now I know that this pointer points to object of some specific type which is defined in anonymous namespace. Sadly VS didn't deduce that tape (based on runtime information). The only thing VS shows me for this pointer to interface is contents of virtual table. So to inspect content of this object I have to instruct Visual Studio to cast down this pointer to that type. Problem is what should I type to satisfy Visual Studio.

Note since this is memory dump breakpoints or continuing an execution are not an option. I'm unable to reproduce issue ion my development environment, so this dump is my best chance to find the issue.

Adding to watches this:

```
(InterfaceImplementation*)(some_pointer->pointer_to_interafece)
```

Doesn't works since VS says:

> identifier "InterfaceImplementation" is undefined

### Possible solution

AFAIK anonymous namespaces actually generate a namespace with random name. So to solve my problem I should find a way to provide this generated random name so I can use full symbol name.

### Question

Is there way to inspect symbols in anonymous namespace?
Can I find my symbol in anonymous namespace somehow to identify that namespace?

Comment: I have a vague recollection of needing to have the debugger stopped at some function in the source file withe local namespace in order for the symbols defined in that namespace to be visible to it. I take it just watching `some_pointer` and expanding it to see the members wasn't enough?

Comment: This is memory dump from production. It stooped where it stopped just by pure chance. As I wrote I have a pointer to interface, VS didn't deduce actual type, so I have to force cast to see content of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've got sudden epiphany.

### Clue found

VS for this pointer shown me contents of virtual table. Happily function listed there were described in human readable form. for example:

```cpp
        [0] 0x00007ff75595b0a0 {MyApp.exe!InterfaceImplementation<`anonymous namespace'::SystemApi>::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)}    void *
```

### Solution

So yes I've forget to mention that `InterfaceImplementation` is actually a template, which instance represents either production or testable version (that it is way it depends in `SystemApi`).

So I just copy paste this part `InterfaceImplementation<'anonymous namespace'::SystemApi>` to the casting and now I see everything I need to see.